# How would I be accessing my remote server via remote desktop?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, remote-access, windows-server-2019

This might be an immature question however, I am trying to setup my Windows Server 2019 for remote connections and I am setting it up for the first time.

I have enabled and setup the following on my server:

- Remote Desktop Services Enabled: Yes
- Remote Desktop Licensing: Yes

So, I am trying to access my Server from home which is outside my workplace network via remote desktop using the IP address which is provided in the server's list:

[image]

[image]

I can see that my IP addresses are not public addresses. How do I set up and use a private IP address for this purpose?

I have enabled the remote desktop on my server and trying to connect to it however when I do, I get this error:

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

What do I need to complete before I can connect to my server from outside the network?

Comment: Why exactly do you have the `Limit Number of Connections` group policy enabled?  You cannot access your server 192.168.1.10 from your workplace.  192.168.1.10 does not exist outside of your intranet.  Your server's IP address does not exist outside of your workplace's network.

Comment: I saw a video on how to setup an RDP server and just went with the flow. It needed the number of connections to be 999999 for unlimited connections while I have only 10 CALS. Should I not do that?

Comment: Based on what you have provided neither the client nor server has a configure that would allow either to reach another.  Are you doing this with the permissions of the Administrator of the server? One does not typically make their Window Server accessible outside of the intranet if it's vital for operations within an intranet.  `169.x.x.x` are intranet addresses.  **It does not appear your server is configured to be accessible outside of your workplace's intranet.**  Your local group policy editor screenshot is from the client NOT the server.  That's why it makes sense to configure that GP.

Comment: Good question. I am setting it up for the first time! I am the admin of the server. I want to set it up in a secure manner and also in a way I can use windows remote desktop connection to connect to the server from my home or anywhere with the correct credentials. I dont know if I have set it up correctly. Help would be highly regarded.

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to correctly set it up?

Comment: When you attempt to connect to the server use the public IP address of the server.   You should be using a VPN server to do what you want.  However, a detailed guide on how to do that is well beyond scope of a question here at Super User.  You have to ask specific questions, about a process, not how to do that the entire process.

Comment: No;  You have not asked a specific answerable question.  If this question is closed, you can [edit] it, in order to have it reopened (provided you solve the reason it was closed).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129383/discussion-between-pynoob-n-and-ramhound).

Comment: `192.168.1.10` is an internal LAN address. Not a WAN address which is how you would connect to it from the outside world. So if your work network admin has not assigned an external IP address (on the WAN) to that machine, you will never be able to connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

First off, what you are proposing - as stated - is foolhardy. Exposing your computer to the wider Internet way is foolhardy.

The missing bit requires modifications on the router. In addition to handling the mapping (im being deliverately vague - if you dont know enough to do this you should not be following some guy on the Internet), consider firewalling rdp to the IP address you are coming from.

A better way to do this would be to set the router up as a vpn server, and then your remote computer to connect over the VPN.  In that way your connection will be much more secure and you dont need to worry about the mapping or firewalling I mentioned above.

Comment: Are there services I can employ to get it done? Where would I go looking?

Comment: Im hesitant to make recommendations  but I know that Teamviewer can do what you want without the technical challenges - and likely with better performance - although it does mean your traffic is routed via there seevices  so you are absolutely trusting them.

Comment: Teamviewer can help remote into a logged in session. What I want is to make proper use of the server i.e. Windows Remote Login concurrent users. I am not sure Team Viewer allows that

Comment: https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/solutions/remote-access/ implies otherwise (It claoms to support headless mode and other things. I have a vague recollection of staff of a company I worked for using it remotely, and Im fairly sure they logged out if their PCs when leaving the office. It was years ago though)